# Extjs 4.0 store - how to find fields in the store (or model)

Tags: model, extjs4, store, extjs

In Ext 3.x I could get an array of field names with this:

```
mystore.fields.keys
```

How can I do this in 4.0?   I can't even see how I can get the model that the store is using (no 'getModel' method).  Do I need to find a record and get the fields that way?  I define the store with :

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Equipments', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.Equipment',

    mycustFunc: function () {
            var myfields = this.fields.keys  (fails!)
```

EDIT:
Thanks... looking in firebug more it seems like this gets what I want:

```
this.model.prototype.fields.keys
```

Answer (score 9):

While there isn't a `getModel()` method for the Store itself, the Proxy holds the Model, so you can simply use `store.getProxy().getModel()` to fetch the Model, and thereby the Model's fields.  For replicating a Store, just use model: `originalStore.getProxy().getModel().modelName.`

Comment: Thanks... looking in firebug more it seems like this gets what I want:

this.model.prototype.fields.keys

Comment: yeah i just checked too, I thought it would be simpler:P ... they made it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

i change the fields from my store,
just like that:

```
myStore.model.setFields(fields);
```